# PHP (setcookie) vs cabeçalho (header )

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers

Vejo alguns frameworks, CMS e afins, fazerem a escrita de cookies direto no PHP com `setcookie` e outros estocam para emitir nos `headers` no final da execução. Queria saber como criar um padrão para a criação dos cookies.

> **PHP**
>
> A função setcookie() define um cookie para ser enviado juntamente com o resto dos cabeçalhos HTTP

---

Devemos criar enviando pelo cabeçalho?

`header( "Set-Cookie: {$name}={$value};" )`

Ou deixar por conta do PHP?

`setcookie( $name , $value )`

Comment: Recomendo usar setcookie() pois é uma função apropriada para fazer esse tipo de ação. Header() também é bom, mas o recomendável é usar setcookie()

Comment: Outra coisa (que a essa altura você já deve saber) é que com `header` teria que usar `urlencode` ou `rawurlencode`. Segue código no Github: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/71c19800258ee3a9548af9a5e64ab0a62d1b1d8e/ext/standard/head.c#L80

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não sabia disso não rs. Teria que usar no `domain`?

Comment: @PapaCharlie então pelo que analisei do código fonte do php é necessário somente o name e o value serem codificados, os demais não.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambas as funções chegam ao mesmo resultado.

Porém o que diferencia o `setcookie()` é a sua facilidade para criação de cookies mais complexos, com data de expiração,  domínio da aplicação que o cookie será usado (www.algumacoisa.com.br), entre outros.

Veja todos os parâmetros que a função aceita:

```
setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

Mais informações na [documentação do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: Não tenho duvidas de como cria-los, era apenas uma questão de escolha do método(A ou B). Tenho minha classe `Cookie` com todos atributos para os cookies e no momento está com `setcookie`, vou manter como padrão. Obrigado

Comment: Só um acréscimo: o `setrawcookie` possui o mesmo facilitador que o gmsantos disse, porém ele não usa `urlencode` no valor. Portanto, não vejo necessidade de usar `header` no caso do PHP.