# Como eliminar COOKIES no PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

Como posso eliminar COOKIES no PHP? Eu sei que pra sessões tem o `session_destroy()` mas e pra Cookies como faço?

Comment: *Relacionado:* [Cookies - PHP (setcookie) vs cabeçalho (header )](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27067/3635)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a propria função [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) mas com valor negativo no terceiro parâmetro (que é o expires), também pode usar [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) com a variável `$_COOKIE` pra eliminar a chave na execução atual:

```
/**
 * Unset cookies
 *
 * @param string $key    Nome do cookie
 * @param string $path   (Opcional) Se definido irá remover o cookie de caminhos especificos
 * @param string $domain (Opcional) Se definido irá remover o cookie de (sub)dominios especificos
 * @param bool $secure   (Opcional) Se definido irá remover o cookie em conexão segura (isto varia conforme o navegador)
 * @return bool
 */
function unsetcookie($key, $path = '', $domain = '', $secure = false)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $_COOKIE)) {
        if (false === setcookie($key, null, -1, $path, $domain, $secure)) {
            return false;
        }

        unset($_COOKIE[$key]);
    }

    return true;
}

//Elimina o cookie pro path atual
unsetcookie('meucookie');

//Elimina o cookie pro path raiz
unsetcookie('meucookie', '/');

//Elimina o cookie de um domínio quando estiver em um subdomínio por exemplo: bar.foo.com
unsetcookie('meucookie', '/', 'foo.com');
```

Como no exemplo da documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#103629

Answer (score 5):

A resposta do [@GuilhermeNascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento) responde muito bem à pergunta, mas gostaria de trazer um acréscimo.

Quando se trata de Cookies, eu não sei se a forma mais correta seria dizer "Eliminar Cookies". O que geralmente se faz para que o Cookie seja "Eliminado" é "invalidá-lo".

Digo isso porque a forma mais comum é definindo um valor negativo para o parâmetro `$expire`. Isso fará com que o navegador entenda que aquele Cookie já "passou do prazo de validade" e não vai enviá-lo ao servidor.

De maneira simplificada, você apaga um cookie assim:

```
 setcookie('quero_apagar_isso', null, -1);
```

Pensado logicamente, alguém poderia pensar que `unset($_COOKIE['quero_apagar_isso'])` funcionaria, mas isso não é verdade.

A variável `$_COOKIE` é como se fosse somente-leitura, pois ela referencia  algo vindo do cliente.

O único caso onde `unset` vai funcionar com uma variável *Super Global* é na variável `$_SESSION`.

Apenas reflita: *Se você usasse `unset($_GET['id'])`, o parâmetro `id` sumiria da url?*. Obviamente, não. Da mesma forma o Cookie não vai deixar de existir só porque você apagou um valor que referencia a ele no PHP.

Da mesma forma que você só poderia apagar o parâmetro `id` de uma url através de redirecionamento, você só vai conseguir apagar o Cookie definindo ele de uma maneira que o Navegador o considere inválido.

Answer (score 1):

Faz da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

unset($_COOKIE['nome_cookie']);
setcookie('nome_cookie', null, -1, '/');
```

Answer (score -3):

apenas:

```
setcookie('nome_cookie', null, -1, '/');
```

é necessártio para limpar os cookies.

Answer (score -4):

Facinho, meu caro. O comando é `unset($_COOKIE['nomeDoCookie']);`

Pronto já irá te ajudar com seu problema.

Isso ae boa sorte!

Comment: -1 Errado. Isso não vai apagar o Cookie, mas vai apenas apagar o valor da variável. Os cookies são tratados diferentemente do que os demais dados.